# How to display error message in angularjs(404)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am doing angularjs application with web api as front end. Whenever some user do not have certain permission I am returning Httpresponsemessage as

```
var message = string.Format("You do not have permission");
                        HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
```

I want to alert above message in angular and I am trying as below.

```
$scope.Update = function () {
        var servCall = ProjectSetting_Service.update(sub);
        servCall.then(function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            });
    }, function (error) {
//How to alert message here

    }
```

May I get some help here! Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try `console.log('error', error);` in your errorCallback function and show the response, you can do this `alert(error.data.message);`

Answer (score 5):

Add a view in your html and show that view in the error try this

```
$scope.showError = false;
$scope.Update = function () {
  var servCall = ProjectSetting_Service.update(sub);
  servCall.then(function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
}, function (error) {
  //alert message  
  $scope.showError = true;    
}
```

In your html

```
<div ng-show="!showError ">
    <p> Everything is going fine :)</p>    
</div>
<div ng-show="showError ">
    <p> 404 sorry</p>
</div>
```

Comment: alert(error.statuscode) something like this can i try to alert 404?

Comment: you can but alert in not the best solution, try adding some custom html in place of 404,  https://www.google.co.in/adsensehfhskdfkjhsdf click on the link and check one example

Comment: yes i know but i am just writing server side code and front end is doing someone else. Testing purpouse i want to show 404 in alert.

Comment: Yes for testing purpose its fine, Accept my answer if you like it :)

Comment: ohh, tell me whats the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135373/discussion-between-saurabh-agrawal-and-niranjan-godbole).

Comment: what alert are you getting in `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`??